# Replace first occurrence of text in a .bat script

Tags: batch-file

I need to replace the first occurrence of `<?php` in a .txt file with `<?php this is a test` from within a .bat file.

If there are further occurrences of `<?php`, they should not be replaced

How can I do this.

Alternatively (although more dangerous)...I could just delete the first line of the file (assuming it will be `<?php`) and replace it with the above, but I don't know how to do that either in batch.

Comment: File manipulation isn't really a strong point of plain old batch here.  There aren't really any useful commands you could use.    I'd consider using a scripting language to do this instead.  Perhaps maybe PowerShell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do these types of (advanced) string manipulations in batch, you need a stronger language for that, for example writing a .NET console application, or using a script language like vbscript or powershell.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this (advanced) string manipulation with something like

```
@echo off
set "infile=C:\temp\myFile.php"
set "outfile=C:\temp\myOut.php"
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "first=1"
(
    for /f "delims=" %%A in ('"findstr /n ^^ %infile%"') do (
        set "line=%%A"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

        set "line=!line:*:=!"
        if defined first (
            if defined line (
                set "replace=!line:<?php=<?php this is a test!"
                if !line! NEQ !replace! (
                  set "first="
                  set "line=!replace!"
                )
            )
        )
        (echo(!line!)
        if not defined first (
            endlocal
            set "first="
        ) ELSE (
            endlocal
        )
    ) 
) > %outfile%
```

Comment: +1 Constantly amazed by what you can do with batch-files... presumably the `(echo(!line!)` construct protects against lines with things like `)` in them... it _looks_ like mismatched `(...)` but from some tests it looks like `echo(` (with no spaces) "confuses" it so it neither reacts to any `)`s in `line` nor prints the surrounding `(...)`. _Must remember!_

Comment: @TripeHound The `echo(` is the key, it's [the most stable version of `echo`](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774#p4554). The encosing parentheses are only to avoid trailing white spaces